# mysql SELECT LIKE must match whole word

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to make this work. I have tried several examples found on Stack but I'm getting errors when I implement it in the code below.

I have tried to use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]$query[[:>:]]'` for instance, but I'm getting unexpected "[" errors. I don't know enough of php/sql to fix this...

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE (`post_title` LIKE '%".$query."%' AND `post_title` LIKE '%".$query2."%') 
OR (`post_content` LIKE '%".$query."%' AND `post_content` LIKE '%".$query2."%') 
OR (`guid` LIKE '%".$query."%' AND `guid` LIKE '%".$query2."%')") or 
die(mysql_error());
```

Edit: 
Sorry I have to add something. There is text in post_content which is more than one word. But I want to search the post_content column for the search word in the whole text. When the text in the post_content column is "I have a band and a brand" I don't want get results like "band" and "brand".

Comment: If you want to match entire word then simply do `LIKE '".$query."'` of `= '".$query."' `

Comment: @Strawberry Can you give an example?

Comment: @Strawberry: would this fix it? $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

Comment: @Strawberry You missed this question: Can you give an example?  and this remark: I don't know enough of php/sql

Comment: @Strawberry Would this be OK? https://ideone.com/KeCHbg

Answer (score -1):

It can be like:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE (`post_title` LIKE '".$query."' AND `post_title` LIKE '".$query2."') 
OR (`post_content` LIKE '".$query."' AND `post_content` LIKE '".$query2."') 
OR (`guid` LIKE '".$query."' AND `guid` LIKE '".$query2."')") or 
die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: If I do it like that I get no results. While there should be.

Comment: Sorry I have to add something. There is text in post_content which is more than one word. But I want to search the post_content column for the search word in the whole text. when I search for "and" I don't want get results like "band".

Comment: When you get 'unexpected "[" ' error, what is the value stored for '$query' ?

Comment: $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE (`post_title` REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$query."[[:>:]]' AND `post_title` REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$query2."[[:>:]]') 
OR (`post_content` REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$query."[[:>:]]' AND `post_content` REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$query2."[[:>:]]') 
OR (`guid` REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$query."[[:>:]]' AND `guid` REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$query2."[[:>:]]')") or 
die(mysql_error());

Comment: I'm looking at the second code which gives better results. The culprit is now the $query2 which can be empty. If it's not empty then I get results. If I leave the query2 form field empty I get No results.